# Java Problem By creating Student Managment Program

Tags: java

A program that registers students, but upon entering a previous student number that has a precedent, it should print "Student already exists" in the "isHere" test function in the "universitaet" class, but it does, in addition to all that, what is the problem here?

```
case 1:
    System.out.println("Bitte Geben sie ihre matrikelnummer ein: ");
    String m = in.nextLine();
    if (!Student.testMN(m)) {
       System.out.println("Die MatrikelNummer ist nicht gultig");
       break;
    }
    if (!uni.isHere(m)) {
        System.out.println("Der Student existiert beriets!");
        break;
    }
    System.out.println("Bitte Geben sie ihre Vorname ein: ");
    String v = in.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Bitte Geben sie ihre Nachname ein: ");
    String n = in.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Geben sie ihre T.C ein: ");
    String t = in.nextLine();
    Student stud = new Student(v , n , m , t);
    uni.addStudent(stud);
    break;
```

```
public class Universitaet {
    Vector<Student> studenten = new Vector();
    private int anzahl_studenten = 0;

    public boolean isHere(String m) {
        for (int i = 0 ; i < studenten.size() ; i++) {
            if (Integer.parseInt(m) == Integer.parseInt(studenten.get(i).getMN())) {
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Java is to Javascript as Pain is to Painting, or Ham is to Hamster. They are completely different. It is highly recommended that aspiring coders try to learn the name of the language they're attempting to write code in. When you post a question, please tag it appropriately - this lets those with knowledge of the language you need help with to see your question.

Comment: I'm not sure what that "isHere" method is supposed to do, but there is just one single scenario in which it would work, being that there are students, and the student you are looking for is the very first.

Comment: Object `uni ` is not instanced in class. Can you provide full code of the first block function? Furhermore, `if (Integer.parseInt(m) == Integer.parseInt(studenten.get(i).getMN()))` why not compare 2 strings directly instead of integers? :D

Comment: @NguaCon - `"05".equals("5")` is `false`. I hope, this example will give you a better understanding of the significance of  `Integer.parseInt` in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your `isHere` method where you are returning `true` in the loop itself. It should return `true` only when the loop has completed and `m` has not matched with `MN` value of any of the students. A correct implementation can be as follows:

```
public boolean isHere(String m) {
    boolean found = true;
    for (int i = 0 ; i < studenten.size() ; i++) {
        if (Integer.parseInt(m) == Integer.parseInt(studenten.get(i).getMN())) {
            found = false;
            break;
        } 
     }
     return found;
}
```

Another implementation can be as follows:

```
public boolean isHere(String m) {
    for (int i = 0 ; i < studenten.size() ; i++) {
        if (Integer.parseInt(m) == Integer.parseInt(studenten.get(i).getMN())) {
            return false;
        } 
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a logical error in your isHere() method. It should be ...

```
public boolean isHere(String m) {
        for(int i = 0 ; i < studenten.size() ; i++){
            if(Integer.parseInt(m) == Integer.parseInt(studenten.get(i).getMN())){
                return false;
            }
         }
         return true;
    }
```